# How to add reaction in discord.py slash command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello Whenever I am trying to add a reaction to my slash command but when i tried to run it the reactions did not show up

```
        msg = await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
        for button in buttons:
            await msg.add_reaction(button)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `InteractionResponse.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_message#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) clearly shows that it **doesn't return anything**, so `msg` will be `None` here...

You can fetch the response that you sent using [`Interaction.original_response()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=send_message#discord.Interaction.original_response):

> Fetches the original interaction response message associated with the interaction.
>
> **If the interaction response was a newly created message** (i.e. **through InteractionResponse.send_message()** or InteractionResponse.defer(), where thinking is True) **then this returns the message that was sent using that response**.